# Using sprintf to convert integer to string seems to ignore 0

Tags: c, string, integer, printf

When I run the following code with an input of '01', value has the value of 1, ignoring the 0. However if i input '301' with the 0 not in the first position the code works.

```
int input;
printf("Enter an number: \n");
scanf(" %d", &input);

char array[10];
int value = sprintf(array, "%d", input);
printf("%d", value);
```

Comment: It's an int, not a string.

Comment: This is to be expected.  The `scanf()` converts both `01` and `1` into the same bit pattern (a bunch of zero bits and a final one bit) — and `sprintf()` cannot tell how many leading zeros were in the text that was converted (if, indeed, any text was converted).  Note that in source code, `0777` and `777` produce very different values; the first is an octal constant, the second a decimal constant.  In decimal input with `scanf("%d", …);`, the leading zeros are ignored; with `scanf("%i", …);`, the leading zeros matter (it is octal again).

Comment: My end goal is to convert the integer into the string so I can extract exact values. How would I do this then if there is a 0 at the beginning?

Comment: @Ben Is `01` converted to an int a different number then `1`? 
What is the `exact value` of `01` when converted to an int ?

Comment: If you want leading zeros in the output, consider `snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "%.5d", input");` which guarantees 5 digits output, with leading zeros if necessary.

Comment: @KamilCuk 01 and 0 both print '1'

Comment: Well, you are printing `sprintf` return value, it will print as many characters it has written into the buffer. In case of `01`, then `input=1` then `snprintf(array, "%d", 1)` will print one character, in case of `0` is will also print one character. Use `printf("%s", array)` to print the buffer. Or just `printf("%d", input)` to print the value....

Comment: @KamilCuk I understand what you are saying but my end goal is to basically convert the int into the char array so I can extract each value by their position, however, when 0 is the leading number it seems to ignore it unless 0 is the only number.

Comment: If you want to read in leading zeros, your best option is to read in the number as a string

Comment: Then save the input to a char array, not to int. You are not interested in the integral value of the numbers, but in each value of the position. This is another question. You posted `sprintf seems to ignore 0`. You want `how to use scanf to extract all numbers by their position in string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to discern leading `'0'` digits is to record the scan offset of input.

```
int n1, n2;
int input;
if (scanf(" %n%d%n", &n1, &input, &n2) == 1) {
  char array[40];
  int width = n2 - n1;
  int text_length = sprintf(array, "%0*d", width, input); // "0" --> Pad with zeros
                                                       // "*" --> Min width in argument list
  printf("%d <%s>\n", text_length, array);  
}
```

`" "` will consume leading white-space. `"%n"` will record the scan text offset position.  `"%n"` does not contribute to the `scanf()` return value.

Limitations: input like `"-123"` and `"+123"` will report 4.

Comment: Note `width` and `text_length` are expected to be the same in this case unless there is a _rare_ print error.

Answer (score 1):

The manual page of `sprintf()` says

> ```
> int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
> ```
>
> `sprintf()`, write to the character string `str`.

Here

```
int value = sprintf(array, "%d", input);
```

`sprintf()` converts the `int` input into `char array`.

For e.g if user entered `input` as integer `123` it conver that into char array `123`. Now it looks like

```
-------------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  \0  |
-------------------------
array
```

and `sprintf()` returns *return the number of characters printed (excluding
       the null byte used to end output to strings).* That means

```
int value = sprintf(array, "%d", input); /* if input = 123(integer) */
printf("%s: ,%d: \n", array,value);/* array: 123(string), value: 3 */
```

*When I run the following code with an input of '01', value has the value of 1, ignoring the 0. ?* `input` is declared as an integer and when user gives `01` then `scanf()` considers only `1` as leading `0` ignored and only `1` gets stored into `array`, the `array` looks like

```
--------------
|  1  |  \0  |
--------------
array
```

*However if i input '301' with the 0 not in the first position the code works.* If user entered `301` then `scanf()` stored `301` into `input` and `sprintf()` converts that `int` into char array & stores into `array` as `301` like

```
     -------------------------
    |  3  |  0  |  1  |  \0  |
    -------------------------
    array
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read a string as a number using the `%d` format specifier, any leading zeros are basically lost.

If you want to keep the leading zeros, you need to read the input as a string.  That way you get exactly what the user entered.  If you additionally want to perform numerical operations, you can then use `strtol` to get the numerical representation.

```
char array[10];
scanf("%s", array);

int input = strtol(array, NULL, 10);
printf("input as number %d, input as string: %s\n", input, array);
```